# Find an expression for a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given the compact set with the boundary $ \left(x-y\right)^{2}+x^{2}=a^{2}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace,a>0 $, I have to find an expression for $ \intop dx\int f\left(x,y\right)dy $ and $ \intop dy\intop f\left(x,y\right)dx $, where $ f $ is some function (dosent really matter what exactly the function is, because it is an exercise with finding bounderies of the integral and changing order of summation.

Now, I cannot really see what exactly the geometric shape of this equation is. Is it still possible to solve and find the bounderies of the integral, just by using the equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help that $|x|\le a$ and $|x-y|\le a$

Comment: The [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/usqnijpfgo) gives you a rotated ellipse.

Comment: @DMcMor I specifically asked if one can solve this without knowing the geometric shape

Comment: @FreeZe sorry, I interpreted "I cannot really see what exactly the geometric shape of this equation is" to be an request for clarification on the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x-y)^2 + x^2 = a^2 \implies (x-y)^2 = a^2 - x^2 \implies x-y = \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\quad  (1)$

Thus,
$y = x \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$. But $(1)$ imposes a constraint on $x$, $a^2-x^2 \geq 0 \implies x\in [-a,a]$.

Therefore, the $\int dx~\int f(x,y)dy$ order is given by $$-a\leq x \leq a$$ $$x - \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \leq y \leq x+ \sqrt{a^2-x^2} $$

For the alternative order, the idea is pretty much the same.

Comment: Solve the quadratic $2x^2-2xy+(y^2-a^2)=0$, where $x$ is the variable and $y$ is a parameter

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot